# sending data from appcontroller to default.ctp - CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, controller, cakephp-2.0

I want to send the below data to default.ctp, I want to display menus in all the pages, I'm using Auth, The problem is if I'm logged in I get the Menus correctly, but if I logout, I'm getting error saying  variable'$topMenu' not found.
The MenuController can be accessed only if logged in.

```
$this->loadModel('Menu');
$this->set('topMenu',$this->Menu->find('all'));
```

Any help on how to solve this?

Comment: Could you post the complete code of your AppController?

Answer (score 0):

Put $this->Auth->allowedActions in your controller and assign it the values of the actions you want to access without logging in.

```
$this->Auth->allowedActions = array('menu');
```